# Why does the Universe resist change?

Tags: cosmology, conservation-laws, universe

Conservation of energy, conservation of momentum, inertia, Lenz's law (that the emf produced by a magnetic field will always oppose the change in magnetic flux), Newton's second law, pair production, etc.

Is there any theory to explain why so many of our laws of physics are dependent on the idea that the Universe, and everything in it, would rather continue as it is without change?

And considering the "stubborn" nature of the Universe, why does it continue to expand when the expansion of the Universe is the greatest change of all?

Answer (score 1):

A rather pedestrian explanation that's perhaps close to what you look for:

$\,\,\,\,\,$ *We look for things that do not change, so that we can make predictions.*

So, when two balls collide, it's evident that the speeds change, the directions of movement change, and if that's all you know, it might seem that anything can happen - you've got no knowledge. But when you notice that $\sum m\mathbf{v}$ and $\sum mv^2$ somehow *do not* change with the collision - then you can predict what will happen. And that's why you care about them and their conservation.

Apart from that, as John Rennie already pointed out in his comments, these conservations laws result from symmetries.